# What's difference between "= remember" and "by remember"?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I see that are two ways to declare a variable with the [remember](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Function0)) API.

The first one is:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun abc() {
    var aa = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
}
```

The second is:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun abc() {
    var aa by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
}
```

Is there any functional difference between the two? Or are they just for convenience?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is just for convenience, to shortify syntax. By using delegate (by keyword) you can skip relating to value because it is done under the hood.

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) you can read

> There are three ways to declare a MutableState object in a composable:
>
> val mutableState = remember { mutableStateOf(default) }
> var value by remember { mutableStateOf(default) }
> val (value, setValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(default) }
>
> These declarations are equivalent, and are provided as syntax sugar
> for different uses of state. You should pick the one that produces the
> easiest-to-read code in the composable you're writing.

Cheers

Answer (score 43):

I've noticed a slight difference between the two expressions.

In case `=` is used

```
@Composable
fun abc() {
var aa = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
}
```

then `var aa` will be of type `MutableState<Boolean>`.

In case `by` is used

```
@Composable
fun abc() {
var aa by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
}
```

then `var aa` will be of type `Boolean`.

Personally, I prefer using `by` to preserve the primitive types.

Comment: This is a very important point.  I think the equals sign is easier to read, but discovered that all my code broke down because I was treating the variable as a boolean (and not MutableState).  +1

Answer (score 8):

in the first case: you have to use "aa.value" whenever you want to use the value of "aa".
in the second case: you don't have to, because under the hood you aren't using the getter of the var.

additional:

- you know that whenever you call or edit a variable you are under the hood calling its getter and setter functions, so when you use "by" you are using another getter and setter which delegated to another piece of code (usually to the function the comes after "by" keyword) and then you do not have to use "aa.value", you just can write "aa" when call it or "aa = true" when you set it.
- "var" have setter and getter functions because it is editable, while "val" have just getter and no setter cause it is not editable (read only).

note: if you want to read more then check this answer for a well understanding of the concept: [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250022/what-does-by-keyword-do-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

One functional difference between them is that if you use by and then try to pass aa into another function where it is edited, that will not work. In that case aa will be a Boolean passed as val, which is not editable. If you use = and pass in MutableState<Boolean> then you can assign to aa.value inside your second function.