# Gradle creating a additional task for int tests

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

So I found a few tutorials on how to create a seperate task to run integration tests in gradle. My int tests are in a separate folder.. ie src/integrationTest

This is what one of them had set up, I just dont understand the line "val integrationTest by sourceSets.creating"?  Is this creating a source set? Other examples have explicit creation of source set in the gradle file..

```
val integrationTest by sourceSets.creating

dependencies {
    "integrationTestImpl"(project)
}

val integrationTestTask = tasks.register<Test>("integrationTest") {
    description = "Runs the integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDirs = integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    mustRunAfter(tasks.test)
}
tasks.check {
    dependsOn(integrationTestTask)
}
```

Comment: The preferred way to do this is via test suites : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#sec:declare_an_additional_test_suite Using this will get you a lot 'for free'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is creating a new source set named `integrationTest`.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250022/what-does-by-keyword-do-in-kotlin) answer on Kotlin delegated properties. It is not specific to Gradle, but the Kotlin language itself. Gradle provides a variety of [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) to make the Kotlin DSL a rich experience compared to the Groovy DSL.