# How does 'by' differ from '=' in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, equals-operator

What is the functional difference between the two lines of code:

```kotlin
private val binding = viewBinding(Fragment::bind)
```

```kotlin
private val binding by viewBinding(Fragment::bind)
```

I tried reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250022/what-does-by-keyword-do-in-kotlin) stack overflow post on what is the `by` keyword used for in Kotlin but, it says that it replaces the getter and setter functions to the expression following the `by` keyword so why have it at all if you can just use `=` instead, to set the object to a particular value?

Answer (score 1):

'**=**' means `binding` is assigned to the value of `viewBinding()` method immediately. It doesn't require any other calls.

'**by**' is used to set a **delegation**. 'by' act as a **getter** of the `binding` to the `viewBinding()` method result. What is does actually, binding won't be result of `viewBinding()` until binding itself is not **accessed**. By using 'by' you can trigger a **lazy initialization**.

more at [Delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html)

Comment: Then what does it mean when you see `by lazy` in some cases?

Comment: `lazy` is executed the first time the property is accessed, and the result is then stored for future access.